# What is the purpose of setting a routeattribute with version for web api using centralrouteprefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am setting up a new web api using mvc and one of the options to configure mvc is "UseCentralRoutePrefix". it takes a new routeattribute as parameter.

In many places i see a version being setup for the route attribute as shown inline:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseCentralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute("api/v{version}"));
    });
}
```

Can anyone explain me the significance of {version} in above piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `UseCentralRoutePrefix` doesn't exist out of the box. I think it's provided by quite a few people as an extension method, with a custom `RouteConvention`, to make it convenient to add a `RoutePrefix` centrally. The idea is you don't have to mark all of your controller methods with a prefix that you may need to use. In your example it is `api/v{version}`

With regards to the significance of `{version}`, it is a route parameter, it can be anything within the curly braces. It means that all of your endpoints are expecting a route parameter. When the action is called this parameter will bind to the version parameter. So, if your controller name is `ValuesController` for example, and you haven't defined the RouteName for the controller, your endpoint will be `api/v1/values`

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult GetValue(int version)
    {
        return new ContentResult { Content = version.ToString() };
    }
}
```

If you call the above action using `api/v1/values`, the output will be 1. I hope that helps.

In addition, the version parameter is usually used when you want to enable versioning either by using `[ApiVersion]` attribute on the action methods or by using the following code in `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            var apiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);

            options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
            options.DefaultApiVersion = apiVersion;
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        });
```

For more details regarding versioning, please read [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning)

Comment: I see. Api Versioning answers my question on business use case of the {version}. By the way how does "api/v1/values" call the "GetValue" action? Is it some kind of default we have set initially.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. WebApi follows some conventions that are aligned with the REST principles. If your action method name starts with Get and is the only method, it will be called automatically. The route `api/v1/values` will be mapped to the action method `GetValues`. If you have multiple methods, you have to define the Route for each action using `[Route]` or `[Http{verb}]` where verb can be Get, Post, Put etc.

In addition, you can also use the `[action`] token if you want to force the action method name e.g. `[HttpGet("[action]")]` will force you to use `api/values/getvalues`